# How to turn off logging in log4c, which is the configuration parameter used in xml file

Tags: log4cxx

I am using log4c library with xml configuration log4crc and I need to figure out how to turn off/on logging.
I could not find any document explaining the parameters in log4crc configuration file,

Answer (score 0):

try seeting the log priority to "notset"

If that doesn't work then make sure the system can't find your log configuration file and unset the environment variables LOG4C_APPENDER and LOG4C_PRIORITY

Answer (score 0):

You could not turn off through set_priority() as log4c `enum`  does not have support for OFF, where as avail in logj

[image]